# How to show a table with 10+ columns in android

Tags: android, material-design, data-tables

since the android screen is small to show a table with 10+ columns 
so, I was wondering what is the best approach to show this kind of table according to material design guidlines
The data from website that should be shown in android looks like this:

[image]

Comment: JonW I would suggest that mobile is pretty different to desktop.

Comment: @LisaTweedie True, however all of the answers in that question are also fair suggestions for a mobile device. For example, your answer is pretty similar to [this one](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/94872/77811) and [this one](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/94873/77811) found on the other question.

Comment: I design for mobile and desktop and they really are very different design experiences. I think it is valuable to have questions focused specifically around mobile UX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well remember that you can go landscape to give you more width for columns.

You could also give users options for which columns to view and hide.

The other option is to pick a few summary columns and then provide an accordion so that they can open up more details on a card on a particular row. This fits in quite well with the material design "look".

[image: Table balsamiq]

Comment: I have included a screenshot of what will be shown in my apk. Does this design applies to what you have mentioned here?

Comment: Well do you think it is. Have a look at some of the other answers and the question JonW referenced.